# SQL выборка из существующей выборки по различным условиям

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Необходимо сделать выборки с различными условиями из уже сформированной выборки.
Сформированную выборку назвал 'r'.
Она состоит из трёх столбцов: userid, age, param.

Необходимо получить 3 значения из выборки 'r':
- среднее значение param по всем пользователям
- среднее значение param по пользователям с возрастом в диапазоне 20-30 лет
- среднее значение param по пользователям с возрастом в диапазоне 31-40 лет

Пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT AVG(r.param),
(SELECT AVG(r.param) FROM r WHERE r.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30),
(SELECT AVG(r.param) FROM r WHERE r.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40)
FROM
(SELECT ...) AS r
```

Выдает ошибку, что таблицы с именем 'r' не существует.
Если в коде заменить `from r` на `from (select ...)`, то работает, но приходится 
3 раза прописывать огромный кусок кода `(select ...)`.

Подскажите, можно ли один раз прописать запрос `(select ...)`, а потом обращаться 
к нему как к таблице по имени? 
Или, возможно, есть какой-то другой способ решить вопрос?
Спасибо

Comment: Какая у вас версия MySQL сервера?

Comment: версия MySQL сервера 8.0

Comment: Используйте [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> версия MySQL сервера 8.0

```
WITH r AS ('текст подзапроса')
SELECT AVG(r.param),
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN r.param END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN r.param END)
FROM r;
```

Для младших версий это было бы

```
SELECT AVG(r.param),
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN r.param END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN r.param END)
FROM ('текст подзапроса') r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще вот так сделать:

```
WITH r AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT AVG(r.param),
       (SELECT AVG(r.param) FROM r WHERE r.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30),
       (SELECT AVG(r.param) FROM r WHERE r.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40)
FROM r;
```

Остается узнать какой способ предпочтительнее.

Comment: Несомненно, предпочтительнее использовать прямой расчёт, а не расчёт в подзапросах, в данном случае явно избыточных.